# Bi Directional folders (Mac to Mac)

Tags: macos, mac, folders, server.app

Currently we are running a system where a group of 12ish Apple Mac computers connect to a Mac Mini Server.

We also have a few off-site teams who need to access said server as well. We would like to know if there's a modern system that allows the user to drop files into a folder which then shares with the server and also shares with the off-site teams. (obviously allowing time for upload/download time)

This would need to be peer-to-peer we do not want to use Cloud Computing.

An example of this being used would be:
Folder on User 1's desktop is populated with files, the same folder appears on the server which also appears on user 2's desktop. Only when the files are requested should they copy from User 1's machine (it would be a 24/7 machine).

I'm aware there are other questions like this on the website already but I couldn't find a definitive answer. We are looking for a professional solution and not necessarily a work around.

Thank you,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It's called cloud storage.

The best one I have used to date is [OneDrive for Business](https://products.office.com/en-US/onedrive-for-business/compare-onedrive-for-business-plans).  This does exactly what you want - which is to drop a file in a designated folder and then it will propagate to all with access to that folder.

Comment: After reconvening with the team we actually need a slightly different solution. Please re-read the original post. Thank you.

Comment: I can appreciate that.  The problem is, most of the solutions require workarounds and in your case, I don't know of any reliable solutions for OS X Server.  We usually had an Active Directory server and windows shares replicated across subdomains (site1 and site2).  AD took care of it.  Every commercial product I know of is either for Windows or Linux or is a fully integrated NAS solution.

Comment: Also I think all solutions have to copy to the server before any other user can see that the file exists. Why do you want the file to only be on the users workstation - this reason might help us to suggest solutions

Comment: After going over your requirements, what you are asking for is not feasible.  How can User 2 who is remote from User 1 *request* a document and User 1 upload it at the time of the request?  The more I think about it, the more I am convinced that you need Document Management like SharePoint.  Send me a contact request - this is what I do for a living.

Comment: If cloud isn't an issue, iCloud Drive does the same and is already integrated in macOS. Dropbox works as well.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for the service and have your own server, try looking at BitTorrent Sync. It's a peer-to-peer server-hosted cloud.

Comment: @NoahL OP said he wanted a **professional solution** and not a "workaround"